# Angular sidenav with draggable element, goes underneath mat-sidenav-content on drag

Tags: angular, typescript, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to drag a picture from the mat-sidenav into the mat-sidenav-content area where it will be placed (drag with copy function). I thought that simply adding drag to a div element in sidenav would make it work, but I think there is some mix up with the z-index, that i can't figure out. The dragged element goes underneath the content area. Note that angular-draggable-droppable is used, because of snapping functionality.

stackblitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/simulator

sidebar.component.html:

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
  <mat-sidenav #sidebarLeft mode="side" opened="true" class="sidebar" fixedInViewport="false">
    <mat-list class="comp-groups">
      <mat-list-item *ngFor="let section of complist.sections">
        <h4 matLine (click)="showComp(section)">{{section.name}}</h4>
      </mat-list-item>
    </mat-list>
        <div class="component-list" *ngIf="selectedCompList">
      <mat-list-item *ngFor="let subsection of selectedCompList.subSections">
        <h4 mat-line>{{ subsection.name }}</h4>
        <div mwlDraggable 
        dropData="{{subsection.name}}"
        dragActiveClass="drag-active"
        [ghostDragEnabled]="true"
        [showOriginalElementWhileDragging] ="true"
        [dragSnapGrid]="snapping"
        (dragging)="dragging($event)">
        <img id="icon" src={{subsection.icon}}/>
        </div>
      </mat-list-item>
        </div>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav #sidebarRight mode="side" opened="true" class="rightSidebar" fixedInViewport="false" position="end">
  <app-sidebar-right></app-sidebar-right>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content class="workspace">
    <app-toolbar class="toolbarRow"></app-toolbar>
    <app-content class="contentContainer" mwlDroppable

  (drop)="onDrop($event)"
  dragOverClass="drop-over-active"
  (dragOver)="dragEnter($event)"
  (dragLeave) = "dragLeave($event)"

  ></app-content>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Hi @JRS , I managed to solved it by using angular-draggable-droppable. Check it out: https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-draggable-droppable/docs/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue by modifying the CSS of the draggable content.

```css
.the-draggable-content {
   position: fixed;
}
```